# Why won't my calender work?

Tags: javascript, html

The point of it is to display a calender (march 2013 right now) and change the css of the current day using javascript. Here's my calender:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td id="1">1</td><td id="2">2</td><td id="3">3</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="4">4</td><td id="5">5</td><td id="6">6</td><td id="7">7</td><td id="8">8</td><td id="9">9</td><td id="10">10</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="11">11</td><td id="12">12</td><td id="13">13</td><td id="14">14</td><td id="15">15</td><td id="16">16</td><td id="17">17</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="18">18</td><td id="19">19</td><td id="20">20</td><td id="21">21</td><td id="22">22</td><td id="23">23</td><td id="24">24</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="25">25</td><td id="26">26</td><td id="27">27</td><td id="28">28</td><td id="29">29</td><td id="30">30</td><td id="31">31</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here's a few days of it isolated:

```
<td id="25">25</td><td id="26">26</td>
```

so it's basically like that for all the days, and this is my js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var day=dateObj.getUTCDate();
      document.getElementById(day).style.text-decoration="underline";
      document.getElementById(day).style.color="red";
    </script>
```

and it doesn't work. I'm assuming the problem is in my JavaScript, so can you please help?

NOTE: the calender itself displays fine but it won't make the current day red or underline it.

EDIT: Com'on guys, I've tried everything. Stop disliking, I thought this place was to help noobs, not to ridicule them.

Comment: You are being downvoted because your post does not show any debugging efforts. For example, check using `console.log(..);` what your variables actually contain.

Comment: It's what they told me to do when I looked it up online.

Comment: I have tried using alerts but they don't even pop-up.

Comment: Who is this "they" you speak of?

Comment: Take a look at the error console..... There are a few errors... `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='`

Comment: error console? Oh yeah! I know what those are.. Yeah, this editor doesn't have one.

Comment: `alert`? ___`alert`___? Use your browsers error console. Even IE6 had one. Every browser has one.

Comment: Then use your Browser. If you say your browser doesn't have one, i won't belive you.

Comment: @j08691  the "they" is this:
         alert(dateObj.getUTCDate(););
          var day=dateObj.getUTCDate();
          alert(day);

Comment: Well, if it does I don't know where it is, I'm using firefox, most recent update. - Found it

Comment: Well, it just says dateObj undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define dateObj as a Date object.

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
document.getElementById(day).style.textDecoration = "underline";
document.getElementById(day).style.color = "red";
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BGkZW/)**

And when referring to styles that are hyphenated in CSS, you camelCase them in JavaScript (e.g. textDecoration vs text-decoration).

Also note that prior to HTML5, IDs that start with numbers are not valid.

Comment: I'm using html5, so that's not the problem. But let me try out your code

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(day).style.text-decoration="underline";
```

All CSS attributes that usually require a hyphen `-` use camelCase instead<sup>*</sup>, since JavaScript cannot take a hyphen in any name/property that is not being accessed with `[]`:

```
document.getElementById(day).style.textDecoration = "underline";
```

<sup>*it gets interpreted as minus, which doesn't make sense in this context</sup>